# Defining outer edge of filled 2d Contour plot in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, contour, r-plotly

**Problem:** I am trying to reproduce a round filled 2d contour plot in R using plotly (have tried ggplot2 also but plotly seemed to be easier).

**Data:** Sample data download link -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Mr5yWVReQckPI6TKLY_vzPT8zWiijKl/view?usp=sharing

The data to be plotted for contour is in a column format and typically called `z` variable, there is `x` and `y` data also available for all values of `z`. A simple dataframe would look like this:

[image: Sample dataframe]

Please ignore the repeat common x and y as I have truncated decimals. The data has about 25000 rows.

**Approach:** I first use akima package to interpolate `z` variable values for given `x` and `y` to map `z` in 2d. This makes the `z` column data fit in a xy grid for 2d plotting and show contours.

**Expected outcome:**
[image: 2d contour plot of z variable]

**Code used:**

```
dens <- akima::interp(x = dt$`Xvalue(mm)`, 
                  y = dt$`Yvalue(mm)`, 
                  z = dt$Values, 
                  duplicate = "mean",
                  xo=seq(min(dt$`Xvalue(mm)`), max(dt$`Xvalue(mm)`), length = 10),
                  yo=seq(min(dt$`Yvalue(mm)`), max(dt$`Yvalue(mm)`), length = 10))

plot_ly(x = dens$x, 
      y = dens$y, 
      z = dens$z, 
      colors = c("blue","grey","red"), 
      type = "contour")
```

**Actual outcome:**
[image: Plotly contour plot]

**Help Needed:**
To refine edges of the actual outcome plot to something of a close match to the expected outcome image.

Many thanks in advance for your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could increase the grid output `z` matrix from `akima::interp()` from default 40x40 to custom using `nx` and `ny` input in function.

And then in `plot_ly()` add `contours = list(coloring = 'fill', showlines = FALSE)` to hide contour lines to get output close to my expected outcome.

So working code is like this:

```
dens <- akima::interp(x = dt$`Xvalue(mm)`, 
              y = dt$`Yvalue(mm)`, 
              z = dt$Values, 
              nx = 50, 
              ny = 50,
              duplicate = "mean",
              xo=seq(min(dt$`Xvalue(mm)`), max(dt$`Xvalue(mm)`), length = 50),
              yo=seq(min(dt$`Yvalue(mm)`), max(dt$`Yvalue(mm)`), length = 50))

plot_ly(x = dens$x, 
  y = dens$y, 
  z = dens$z, 
  colors = c("blue","grey","red"), 
  type = "contour",
  contours = list(coloring = 'fill', showlines = FALSE))
```

[image: Actual outcome]

Plotly contour plot reference was very helpful in this case:
https://plot.ly/r/reference/#contour